# MongoDB Query: Update or push an object in array of object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have the following object in regions collection:

```
{
    "_id": "5e873652b8e8132380343984",
    "region": "Europe",
    "countries": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Italy"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Spain"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to update a specific country in the countries array based on the id, if the id does not exist, I want to push a new country.

I have the following query which works fine and update a specific country:

```
Region.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: someId, "countries.id": country.id },
    { $set: { [".countries.$"]: country } },
    { new: true }
);
```

But if the country does not exist in countries object, it doesn't push the country.

Answer (score 0):

in option field you may should try this:

```
{ new: true, upsert: true}
```

Comment: {
    "error": {
        "ok": 0,
        "errmsg": "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.",
        "code": 2,
        "codeName": "BadValue",
        "name": "MongoError"
    }
}

Comment: this error occur due to this line..
{ $set: { [".countries.$"]: country } }